# Print a label dymo doesn't work

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dymo

I am using `TDymoDrucker` class in Delphi to print labels. I have created the standard label fields using Dymo Label v.8.

In a Labelform, i am sending variables on click of button to TDymo Drucker class

```
procedure TFormButton.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Print : TDymoData; 
begin
  PrintData.selected     := 'Button1';
  PrintData.Nummber      := 1234;
  PrintData.Name :='Example1';
  DymoData.Print(PrintData); //Passing parameters to Dymodrucker classwhere it checks for printer status and label fields
end;
```

I handle all operations to check whether all the fields and drivers installed in DymoDrucker class and finally using **`DymoAddIn.Print(1, true)`** I am able to print the label.

But on click of another button in the same form

```
procedure TFormButton.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Print : TDymoData; 
begin
  PrintData.selected     := 'Button2';
  PrintData.Model      := 4567;
  PrintData.ModelName :='Example2';
  DymoData.Print(PrintData);
end;
```

I handle all operations to check whether all the fields and drivers installed in DymoDrucker class and finally using **`DymoAddIn.Print(1, true)`**, I am not able to print the label. It doesn't show any error message or failure.
Could someone enlighten me why it is? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now, I have now created a new label using an existing sample(before i was using test) in DYMO SDK v.8 and have added fields using Address field(Dynamical) instead of Text field(static) which is static. It prints as expected now.